# How to fix MacBook Pro (2018 13") Keyboard lag?

Tags: macbook-pro, keyboard, touch-bar

I noticed that there's a small lag (~1 second) when entering text after the keyboard backlight is gone off. 
I have set to turn off keyboard lights after 10 seconds of inactivity (attached screenshot).
[image]

Any help to fix the issue is appreciated.

EDIT: I also noticed that this lag is global when the blacklights  get turned off and also when it turns back on when’s typing. YouTube and many other screen items hang and resume.

EDIT2: What I have done so far:

1. I did boot up in Safe Mode and the issue was not there in the Safe Mode. But when I boot up back in normal mode the issue was there again.
2. Contacted Apple Support, reset SMC, NVRAM, reinstalled MacOS Issue was not resolved.
3. Factory reset (erase hard drive, reinstall MacOS). Issue is still present.

What I noticed:

1. When the keyboard backlight goes off and comes back in, ControlStrip process causes a CPU spike which can be seen in activity monitor.
2. If I set the Touch Bar to show F1, F2, etc. keys, then the issue goes away.

Comment: I also noticed that this lag is global when the backlights get turned off and also when it turns back on when typing. youtube or many other screen items in motion hangs and resumes,

Comment: Possible duplicate of [The Keyboard on my iMac seems to be typing slow and garbled](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/269404/the-keyboard-on-my-imac-seems-to-be-typing-slow-and-garbled)

Comment: The suggested duplicate question doesn't have a solution. Do I still mark this as a duplicate?

Comment: Have you tried what is in the answer there?

Comment: @DManokhin Yes. But doesn't solve my issue.

Comment: @ShamalKarunarathne Did you try booting into safe mode? Was the issue still there? If so, please include that in your question.